# How can I configure my flutter app to web

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications

I have a working mobile application and want to make it into a web app as well. I already ran flutter create but when I run it on web, it gives me a blank screen. I don't know how to get what is showing on my mobile app to show on the screen.[image]

Do I need to change the code or run another command in my terminal? I'm not sure what to do.
**Here is the output in my terminal**

```
Recreating project ....
  web\favicon.png (created)
  web\icons\Icon-192.png (created)
  web\icons\Icon-512.png (created)
  web\index.html (created)
  web\manifest.json (created)
Running "flutter pub get" in sellapp...                             5.1s
Wrote 8 files.

All done!
In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd .
  $ flutter run

To enable null safety, type:

  $ cd .
  $ dart migrate --apply-changes

Your application code is in .\lib\main.dart.
```

Comment: What was the output in terminal?

Comment: @p2kr Hi, here is my output

Comment: check developer tools for any errors. Use dart print() to pinpoint the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try these options:

1. flutter create  (repairs any broken files)
2. flutter clean && flutter pub get  (repairs dependencies)
3. Try a different browser and/or with an internet connection (it is required to download certain files for a web app.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I tried 1 and 2 but they still gave me the blank screen, I also tried another browser, edge, but it still gives me the blank screen. Is there anything I need to do with the code, I don't know much about web apps.

Comment: Make sure you have internet connection. and also sufficient ram and updated flutter. Also, pls share main.dart code